# How to do multiple finds with Java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

Given the following data structure:

Class Address contains:

```
       AddressId  primary key
       Type       can be "MAIL" or "LEGAL"
       Address    text field containing address
       PersonId   foreign key to another Person Class
```

Scenario 1 pseudo code:

```
List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
addresses.add(new Address(1,"MAIL","123 Main St",1));
addresses.add(new Address(2,"LEGAL","456 Main St",1));

//In this scenario I want the "MAIL" record to be returned
addresses.stream().filter(e->e.getType().equals("MAIL")).findFirst().orElse(...);
```

Scenario 2 pseudo code:

```
List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
addresses.add(new Address(1,"LEGAL","891 Main St",2));

//In this scenario I want the "LEGAL" record to be returned
addresses.stream().filter(e->e.getType().equals("MAIL")).findFirst().orElse(...);
```

Scenario 3 pseudo code:

```
List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();

//In this scenario null or empty optional will be returned
addresses.stream().filter(e->e.getType().equals("MAIL")).findFirst().orElse(...);
```

Much appreicated if someone can help out with the stream line of code above that can handle all 3 scenarios.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand Scenario 2: why filtering on MAIL should produce the LEGAL address? Also, what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Just make a method that takes the type and a default

Comment: What do you mean, "handle all three scenarios"?  Do all three at once?  Choose between one of the three?

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking right now.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to state what I need.  Basically, I need a default method, lets call it getDefaultAddress().  This method will retrieve a list of address for a person.  If the list of address has a MAIL type address, return it because that's what I want as my first choice.  If it doesn't, check to see if there's a LEGAL type.  Again return the LEGAL if it is there otherwise return null or empty optional.  Is it possible to do this with a one liner stream code or do I need to use two stream?

Comment: How safe is the assumption that `Type` is either, `"MAIL"` or `"LEGAL"`? If you can rely on it, you can simply use `addresses.stream().filter(e -> e.getType().equals("MAIL")) .findFirst().orElse(addresses.isEmpty()? null: addresses.get(0));`

Comment: @Holger A person may not have any addresses at all so this one liner needs to handle that as well.

Comment: My suggested one-liner solution will handle the case of no addresses, my only question was whether there could be other `Type`s besides `"MAIL"` and `"LEGAL"`. If not, it will do the right thing.

Comment: @Holger Misread your statement, but yes, there can be other address type in the list besides MAIL and LEGAL.  I'm just using those two for simplicity.

Comment: Then you need two searches: `addresses.stream().filter(e -> e.getType().equals("MAIL")) .findFirst().orElseGet(()->addresses.stream().filter(e->e.getType().equals("LEGAL")) .findFirst().orElse(null))`. Using `orElseGet(Supplier)` ensures that the second search only happens when the first didn’t find a match.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, much better than using two streams with if conditions :). I can't close so whoever can, do so please.

Answer (score 0):

If your list of Address objects is not very big I would group them in a HashMap:

```
    List<Address> addresses = getAddressesFromStream(); // populate this list with all your Address objects

    // now populate the HashMap
    Map<String, List<Address>> typeMap = new HashMap<String, List<Address>>();

    for (Address address: addresses) {
        String type;
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(address.getType())) {
            type = "EMPTY";
        } else {
            type = address.getType();
        }

        List<Address> group;
        if (!typeMap.containsKey(type)) {
            group = new ArrayList<Address>();
            typeMap.put(type, group);
        }

        group = typeMap.get(type);
        group.add(address);         
    }
```

hope that fits your problem.